# Not able to bind Azure function to CosmosDB

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I have made a Azure function (http-trigger) and deployed it in the portal using Visual Studio 2019.

The function works fine and I now will add a binding to my CosmosDB. I navigate to my function and click on “Integration”. Now I see the trigger, the function and input and output bindings.

I should be able to add a new input binding here. But I have no “add”button. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add it on the Portal because you are authoring the Function on VS, your screenshot shows that this is a Pre-compiled Function (basically it is compiling in your machine and publishing the DLLs), so you cannot alter it because it's already compiled.

The only scenario where you can add or remove Inputs or Outputs on the Portal is when the Function was created and authored (code written) in the Portal or on `csx` files, meaning you can actually edit the source code in the Portal itself.

Comment: Well, that was an clear answer. Thank you. Actually, I thought that might be the reason, but I cannot find anything telling me what to do instead. Do you know?

Comment: If you want to add a new Input to your Function, you'd have to go to VS, and add the Input to your Function signature. For Cosmos DB Input, please check the doc here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2-input?tabs=csharp, you'd have to add the `[CosmosDB ..]` like you currently have your Trigger.